# Is spark persist() (then action) really persisting?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, persistence

I always understood that `persist()` and `cache()`, then action to activate the DAG, will calculate and keep the result in memory for later use. A lot of threads here will tell you to cache to enhance the performance of frequently used dataframe.

Recently I did a test and was confused because that does not seem to be the case.

```
    temp_tab_name = "mytablename";
    x = spark.sql("select * from " +temp_tab_name +" limit 10");
    x = x.persist()
    x.count() #action to activate all the above steps
    x.show() #x should have been persisted in memory here, DAG evaluated, no going back to "select..." whenever referred to
    x.is_cached #True
    spark.sql("drop table "+ temp_tab_name);
    x.is_cached #Still true!!
    x.show() # Error, table not found here
```

So it seems to me that x is never calculated and persisted. The next reference to x still goes back to evaluate its DAG definition `"select..."` .Anything I missed here ?

Comment: does my response answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is below  ... here is some additional documentation for "uncaching" tables => https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html ... and you can confirm the examples below in the Spark UI under "storage" tab to see the objects being "cached" and "uncached"

```
# df method
df = spark.range(10)
df.cache() # cache
# df.persist() # acts same as cache
df.count() # action to materialize df object in ram
# df.foreach(lambda x: x) # another action to materialize df object in ram
df.unpersist() # remove df object from ram

# temp table method
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_sql")
spark.catalog.cacheTable("df_sql") # cache
spark.sql("select * from df_sql").count() # action to materialize temp table in ram
spark.catalog.uncacheTable("df_sql") # remove temp table from ram
```

Comment: sorry - forgot to include df.cache() ... these are the correct methods for data-frame caching/uncaching ... please update your question to be more specific if this is not what you are looking for @Kenny

Comment: Sorry you did not answer the question. I am not asking how to cache, uncache. I am asking why caching/persisting did not work as expected.

Comment: I ran your example and never received a "table not found" error ... I don't think providing correct information despite misinterpreting your question calls for a down vote, but thanks for clarifying what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`cache` and `persist` don't completely detach computation result from the source.
It just makes best-effort for avoiding recalculation. So, generally speaking, deleting source before you are done with the dataset is a bad idea.

What could go wrong in your particular case (from the top of my head):

<s>1) `show` doesn't need all records of the table so maybe it triggers computation only for few partitions. So most of the partitions are still not calculated at this point.</s>

2) spark needs some auxilliary information from the table (e.g. for partitioning)

Comment: 1. _count_ had to touch all partitions; the action is exclusively for forcing evaluation 2. Are you sure to imply that the partitioning changes ?

Comment: 1. you are right. 2. My main point is that it's not safe to corrupt the source even if you've cached the RDD. What actually triggered such behavior - is mostly guessing.